All possible combinations of itertools
good morning everyone.
I'm new to development and I would like to know if there is a possibility of trying all possible combinations of letters and numbers together in a single word of 51 characters and saving it in a TXT file.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
